# Led Ballast using Flyback Converter Topology

Tags: led-driver

I have a question regarding flyback converter control.
I am currently trying to create a LED ballast using flyback converter topology, however, I am unable to produce the voltage 10V and current 1A that I would like to get. I suspect that the problem is with the control system that I have designed but i cannot figure out what went wrong.
The given parameters are Vin = 240Vac 50Hz, Po = 20W, fsw = 200kHz.

I have attached a photo of the circuit diagram created using PSIM and I would appreciate it if you guys can help me with this.
Thank you.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Show oscilligrams of Vgs, Vds, Id, Vsec and Isec! What _do_ you get?

Comment: (1) You could make this a lot easier on yourself and your readers by cleaning up the schematic. Try and remove unnecessary kinks and angles in the connections by lining up components. (2) Turn off the grid before taking the screen-grab. It improves legibility. (3) What is the triangle symbol on the gate of the MOSFET? (4) "*I am unable to produce the voltage 10V and current 1A that I would like to get.*" What *are* you getting? Is the transistor stuck on or off or does it oscillate? Put all the info in your question rather than sprinkled through the comments.

Comment: When you follow a reference design , choice of parts for simulation is critical and layout for performance. Use Ti.com ‘s tools that gives everything so you can learn

Comment: So many stange things going on. Did you swap Vds and Vgs? Add values to your components in the schematic. Make sure you have a table true on-off PWM section feeding the gate. What's your current senese resistor value?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the TI LM3444.

LINK: [LM3444 240V Flyback Eval Board](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva462f/snva462f.pdf)

[image: LM3444 Flyback schmatic]